# Truth or Reality: what fits best?

Tags: vocabulary

I read an article title '`Truth about denial of gravity`'. The title seems to be giving an impression that the writer would support the denial but indeed he was against the denial. He believed in the gravity theory. The question came in my mind was:

Is the use of the word 'truth' right here? When you actually are denying the denial because 'truth'  means:the true facts about something, rather than the things that have been invented or guessed

So, I think he should have chosen the word 'reality' in the title because to me, the word 'truth' supports the subject and the word 'reality' shows that you are against it and means to present the facts that will support your denial to the subject. In short, if I say 'Truth about...' it means I am supporting the theory/idea but if I say 'Reality about...' it means with the help of facts I am revealing that the theory/idea is baseless.

So the title should have been: `Reality about denial of gravity`

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: If he had supported the denial he would have called his article 'The truth _of_ the denial of gravity.' What you call 'the true facts about something' includes the fact that those who deny it are wrong. _Reality about_ doesn't mean anything different, but it isn't idiomatic as the title of an article.

Comment: @ Kate Bunting So is the title right? Why asking coz he didn't support the denial. He was against the denial.

Comment: Read my first sentence again! There is nothing wrong with the title and it doesn't imply that he supports the denial.

Comment: Rephrase it if you want to be able to more easily parse it: *The truth about gravity denial.* The title itself says nothing at all about whether the author believes or doesn't believe in gravity. The article that follows could either support those people who deny gravity, or criticize them. The only thing the title itself communicates is that there's going to be an attempt made to provide objective facts on the matter.